# Can I find out which tags I have created?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, search, taxonomist-badge

Can I find out which tags I have created? This would be interesting to know.

The tags could be highlighted on the users page for example.

Comment: There was some talk earlier that tag stats pages (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=java&sort=stats&pagesize=15) will contain info about creator & creation date, but it hasn't been implemented. (And yeah, it wouldn't be the same as what you suggest.)

Answer (score 15):

Having recently won a Taxonomist badge, totally by surprise, I'd love to know which if any tag I've created.

I looked at my [list](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459?tab=stats#sort-top) of 373 tags, where I can only see 50. I can't identify a single one in which I owned the earliest question. The closest I saw was [Lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=lucene&page=5&sort=newest&pagesize=50), and I know that wasn't me.

I don't think the information would cause gaming. I think gaming type users would easily just make a pen-and-paper list of tags they know they created.

Comment: I'd try to help you but your badge has been awarded too recently so I can't track it down too efficiently.

Comment: [You, sir, are the proud creator of `[alert]`.](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=459)

Comment: @PopularDemand Thanks; I don't think I saw that there a few months back.

Answer (score 13):

Although this is marked [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), it *is* possible for a tag you've already won Taxonomist for. Simply click the Taxonomist badge in the bottom section of your main profile page to be told which tag it was awarded for.

Alternatively, use this URL:
`http://SITE_NAME/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=YOUR_USERID`

Comment: To be fair, I should point out that the "click on a tag to see why you have it" feature didn't exist at the time this question was asked. So... consider it pointed out.

Answer (score 7):

You can now find this out by using https://data.stackexchange.com/, e.g. by using these queries:

- [Tag 'Ownership' - Taxonomist](https://data.stackexchange.com/biology/query/196683/tag-ownership-taxonomist)
- [How close are you to a Taxonomist Badge](https://data.stackexchange.com/biology/query/87763/how-close-are-you-to-a-taxonomist-badge)

Comment: The links are for biology.  Neither query is working on stackoverflow (too much data probably)

Answer (score 6):

I think the concern here is that if people know what tags they have created they might start using it on dubious questions to try and get the Taxonomist badge. I could definitely see that happening, considering as it is some people *do* know they created a tag and push it on questions sometimes.

Other than that, I can definitely remember thinking I created a juicy one months ago but I can't remember what it was for the life of me, so I would like to know.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't get awarded for using your own tags.

Comment: After all, if you luck-out and make a juicy-one, others will use it and you won't care if you are restricted from getting points for using it :)

Comment: You still don't have the badge > 10 years later so I guess it wasn't that juicy :)

Answer (score 6):

It is unlikely we will do this (that is, show who created a tag) due to the Taxonomist badge gaming concerns outlined above.. and over and over and *over* in about fifty other posts on meta.

I can't see anything good come of making this information public.

Comment: Does this mean you would like me to keep such information private? Or I could only reveal tags created by users who already received a badge?

Comment: So keep it private.  It sounds like most people here only want to know what tags they themselves have created.