# Is there a feed for newly created tags?

Tags: support, tags, feed

Is there a feed for the questions using one of the newly created tags, and maybe the ones I created?

Answer (score 1):

The [10k-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) page includes the 16 most-recently-created tags.

Being able to know which tags you created [has been explicitly declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82/can-i-find-out-which-tags-i-have-created), although if you earn [Taxonomist](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/11/taxonomist) you *are* told which tag it was for.

Comment: I don't have access to the moderator tools because of insufficient reputation. Bit there is [new tags tab](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new) which also has a timestamp.