# Show a tag's creator on the tag wiki page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-creation, taxonomist-badge

Seems like it'd be simple to have the Tag Wiki page for a Tag show who is responsible for creating it.

I'd limit it to tags with at least 5 questions or more, that way those of us who have accidentally created a misspelled tag won't be overly embarrassed.

Comment: I'm not necessarily against this, but I don't understand how it adds value. Why should I care which user suggested a tag? Seems kind of like those useless posts on some websites that say nothing but "FIRST!" Admittedly, this could help people who are confused about whether they're on the road to Taxonomist, but that seems like quite an edge case.

Comment: It's not a huge priority, but then again it's a really small thing to implement.  I can see having it for a few reasons: taxonomist identification and tracking, future badges maybe based on highly-used, good tags, our insatiable search for knowledge, etc.

Comment: You have seen that [this has been explicitly declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82/can-i-find-out-which-tags-i-have-created/6822#6822), I suppose?

Comment: @AakashM, well I'd definitely been there in the past, it's a different request here, but definitely the same decline will apply, though it was 2 years ago, so maybe they've changed their mind :)

Comment: @PopularDemand Actually, it is "The frist!", but I agree with you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If a tag has a related [Taxonomist badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist), the creator will now be shown on its tag wiki/info page.

Comment: Likely related: ["created" date and user displayed on tag wiki refer to different events](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250398)

Comment: [Tag wiki creation?](http://i.imgur.com/02NJHQw.png) Next build will show when the tag itself was created.  Wiki creation can be found in its revision history.

Comment: Is it possible to find the creator is if the Taxonomist badge hasn't been awarded yet?