# "created" date and user displayed on tag wiki refer to different events

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-wiki

I edited the [<kbd>formcollection</kbd>](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/formcollection/info) tag today, and my edit has just been approved.

But the *created* date looks to be the date of when the tag wiki was created, while the linked user is the [one who originally created the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=60286) several years ago:

[image: screenshot of tag wiki page]

The date and user should be from consistent events (either the tag creation, or the creation of the tag wiki), and it should probably be more specific about which this information refers to.

Comment: I'll go out on a limb and [blame Mr. Dixon for this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247148/150235)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's my bad; next build will show the tag's creation date.  Wiki creation can still be found in its revision history.

Comment: Sorry to hijack your (accepted) answer, but did that "build" ever happen? If so, I'd appreciate your feedback about [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306949/286501) I posted a few minutes ago, and which seems to me like this issue is still open (or is it rather back again?).