# Can I check a tag's creator if the Taxonomist badge hasn't been awarded?

Tags: feature-request, support, tags, tag-creation, taxonomist-badge

According to the accepted answer for *[Show a tag's creator on the tag wiki page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108239/351462):*

> If a tag has a related [Taxonomist badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist), the creator will now be
>   shown on its tag wiki/info page.

I recently created the usage guidelines for the [Discord](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/discord) tag on Super User, but I'm not sure if I'm listed as the creator or not.

**Is it possible to check who created a tag if the Taxonomist badge hasn't been awarded yet?**

Comment: Not currently, no.

Comment: Using [Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) to check the tag creator was suggested in some posts: [Can I find out which tags I have created?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82#251034) and [Can you tell who created a tag](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25038#25041) (Mathematics Meta). However, they are not 100% reliable - for example, the post where the was created might have been deleted in the meantime and therefore no longer shown in SEDE.