# List of tags created by me

Tags: support, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I find out which tags I have created?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82/can-i-find-out-which-tags-i-have-created)

In any Stack Exchange site, is there a way to filter out the list of tags created by me?

Comment: The answer from the duplicate is: no, except that if you earned the taxonomist badge (created a tag used by 50 questions) you can click on it in your profile to see which tag it was awarded for ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=459)).

Answer (score -1):

**You can't see the whole list of tags created by you.**

But, [according to Popular Demand](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108247/159251)

> it is possible for tags you've already won
>   [Taxonomist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/11/taxonomist) for.
>   Simply click the Taxonomist badge(s) in the bottom section of your main
>   profile page to be told which tags they were awarded for.
>
> Alternatively, use this URL:
>
> ```
> http://SITE_NAME/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=YOUR_USERID
> ```